# Join tables with multiple results

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: one contains list of businesses and another list of phone numbers.

I am trying to output the list of businesses from the first table and join second table with the numbers. The problem I have is that I can have multiple numbers for the same business, so when I output results I get multiple records for the same business, instead of having single business record with multiple phones. Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    busName,
    busAddress
FROM business_profile
LEFT JOIN business_numbers ON (business_numbers.num_ID = business_profile.bus_ID)
WHERE busMemID = 33
```

I suppose I can run first query and then second one for numbers under each business, but I think there's gotta be a way to combine both in one. What am I missing.

Comment: You are saying you have first and second query but I did not see where is your second query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use `group_concat`:

```
select bp.busname, group_concat(bn.busaddress separator ',') busaddresses
from business_profile bp
    left join business_numbers bn ON bn.num_ID = bp.bus_ID
where busMemID = 33
group by bp.busname
```

This will return a single row for each distinct `busname`, combining the addresses into a single field separated by a comma.